# IIS Re-write Rule Reverse Proxy

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, iis-8

I have a reverse proxy rule in IIS

I need requests to http://www.myapp.com/rp/functionName to proxy to

```
http://127.0.0.1/functionName
```

Ie drop the /rp

Here is what I have but it is passing the /rp

```
http://i59.tinypic.com/2vvj343.png
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern: (.*)rp/(.*)
Action:  http://127.0.0.1:1337/{R:2}
```

Solved this.